# Some questions about the use of CUT in this Prolog exercise

Tags: prolog

I am studying Prolog for an university exam using SWI Prolog and I have some doubts about the differences between two different solution of the following problem:

> Define the clause **count(X, L, NumX)** where X is an atom, L is a
>   list and NumX is the number of occurrences that X appears in L.

This is the first solution:

```
count0(_,[],0).

count0(A, [A|Tail], N) :-
            count0(A,Tail,N1), % L'elemento cercato appare N1 volte nella sottolista
                N is N1+1.     % N vale N1+1

count0(A, [B|Tail], N) :-
            A\=B,            % A è diverso da B
        count0(A,Tail,N). % N è il numero di occorrenze di A nella sottolista
```

This is the second solution:

```
count1(_,[],0).

count1(A, [A|Tail], N) :- !,
                      count1(A, Tail, N1),
              N is N1+1.

count1(A, [_|Tail], N) :- count1(A, Tail, N).
```

My problem is that I am not understanding what role it plays by the CUT in the second version

I know that the CUT prevents backtracking in the specific point where the CUT is put.

The first version of the program do a check if A is different from B in the second rule (I need this? if the first rule is failed so it means that A don't unify with the HEAD of the List so the Head of the list it is different from the element in A)

The second version don't execute this check in the second rule but put a cut in the first rule...

It maybe depends by the fact that (in the second version) if I don't prevent backtracking happens that: after that Prolog give me the first (correct) response, if I force the backtracking using ; happens that use the second rule:

```
count1(A, [_|Tail], N) :- count1(A, Tail, N).
```

taking a different branch in the computation and in that branch I have no N is N+1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version leaves a choicepoint in the second clause whereas the second version commits (with the cut) to that clause when it enters the second clause.

The first version needs to check explicitly that the item is different from the head of the list because, **upon backtracking**, the third clause will be executed regardless of whether the second clause succeeded before.

You can see it for yourself if you trace both procedures with a simple input list of say 1 element.

```
?- count0(a,[a], Count).
```

The first version of your program will match the item with the head of the list, and perform recursion. However it will leave a choice point there to see other alternatives if required.
Then recursion ends because of the base case (empty list), and you get your result of *Count=1*.

If you now ask prolog for other alternatives, it still has that choicepoint so it will try the thirc clause. If you dont explicitly check that A and B are different, it will recursively call itself (again with the empty list) and return *Count=0* which is a wrong answer!

Now, the second version of your program (the one that uses the cut). When prolog enters the second clause with item a, it commits with the cut, so it will not leave a choice point. Now you do recursion and end with the correct result of *Count=1*.

If you now ask prolog for other alternatives, it will say that there are nothing left to check.
As a result of the cut, it is not necessary to check that A and B are different anymore because you are sure they will be different as otherwise the second clause would have commited and the third clause would not be tested.

Comment: Ok, now it is more clear for me...the last question is: in the second version of the program (that use the cut) the order of the rule it is important, is it right?

Comment: @AndreaNobili: yes, it's important. If you swap the two last clauses you will get incorrect results (and also the right one).